# How to get a licence to fly a drone in the city of Prague for a week?

Tags: czech-republic, prague, drones

**

FORWARDED TO drones.stackexchange:
https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/how-to-get-a-licence-to-fly-a-drone-in-the-city-of-prague-for-a-week

**

I hope this is the right place to ask, I don't know here else to go.

I would like to take my drone and go fly in the city of Prague - it's super beautiful there during lockdown. (I'm close by anyway so don't worry, I'm staying save) But -

According to Czech law it's illegal to fly a drone within city borders. You need to get an extra licence/allowance for that. My own shortcoming is, I cannot speak Czech.

Does anyone of you have any prior experience in getting this licence? I read that you can apply for such a licence, but I neither know where nor how. On the other side, I read that people already got into trouble, especially when flying in Prague (residency of the president, etc. etc.)

I do have a registration and the required European licence to fly a drone. I'm really looking for specific allowance for Prague.

Comment: The appropriate place would seem to be [Drones and Model Aircraft](https://drones.stackexchange.com).  They already have a bunch of questions about licenses in various countries.

Comment: Thank you, I will try there as well. But I'm not sure if the Drones and Model Aircraft group is just technical - but they still might be able to help.

Comment: It's not just technical, there are questions on licenses in the US, Israel, France from my quick look at it.  IMHO it's the best place to start.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on an other Stack Exchange site and has been asked there. (If it goes unanswered or gets deleted, please edit this question so we can re-open.)

Comment: By the way @mods, I believe we do accept question migrations to the Drones.SE site.

Comment: Yeah, migrating a question is better than closing and cross-posting.

Comment: It was reposted before a mod saw it, I felt it was better closed than migrated and then closed as a duplicate.